# How to update local repository

Tags: git, github

This is probably a basic question, but let’s say I just cloned a GitHub repo to my computer. and then someone else working on the project changes something on the Github repo. How could I update my local code to be the same as the GitHub code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+update+local+repository

Answer (score 15):

To update your local repository with remote repository you can use

`git pull`

else if you want to update a specific branch you can use

`git pull origin <branch_name>`
replace <branch_name> with your branch

The git pull command first runs git fetch which downloads content from the specified remote repository. Then a git merge is executed to merge the remote content refs and heads into a new local merge commit.

also @Jeff Bennett has answered for a similar type of question, for more information you can refer [update(pull) a branch before a pull/merge request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65500465/how-to-updatepull-a-branch-before-a-pull-merge-request)